# Zend - doctrine 2 insert data / associations mapping

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

i finally set up my mapping for my two tables, i can now join tables via the querybuilder..

however, i cant add data to the join column, its keeps saying null.

my account entity:

```
namespace Entities\Users;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="\Entities\Users\Account")
 * @Table(name="account")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Account extends \Entities\AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(name="accid", type="bigint",length=15)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $accid;

    /** @Column(name="name", type="string", length=255) */
    protected $name;  

    /** @Column(name="profileid", type="integer", length=255) */
    protected $profileid; 


    /** @Column(name="acc_added_date", type="datetime", columnDefinition="datetime", nullable=true) */
    private $acc_added_date;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Profiledetails")
     * @JoinColumn(name="profileid", referencedColumnName="pid") 
     */
    private $account;
```

and my profiledetails entity:

```
namespace Entities\Users;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="\Entities\Users\Profiledetails")
 * @Table(name="profiledetails")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Profiledetails extends \Entities\AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * @Id @Column(name="pid", type="bigint",length=15)
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $accid;
    /** @Column(name="name", type="string", length=255) */
    protected $name;
    /** @Column(name="profileid", type="integer", length=255) */
    protected $profileid;
    /** @Column(name="acc_added_date", type="datetime", columnDefinition="datetime", nullable=true) */
    private $acc_added_date;
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="account")
     * @JoinColumn(name="pid", referencedColumnName="pid")
     */
    private $stances;
```

i use to use :

```
    $postdata array ('name'=>'jason');
    $entity =new \Entities\Users\Account;
    $obj->setData($postdata);

    $this->_doctrine->persist($obj);
    $this->_doctrine->flush();
    $this->_doctrine->clear();
```

and it doesnt add..  what the way to add data to the parent table where all linked tables get updated?  because before i could enter a profileid and now its null  because i used it as a the joined column..

Comment: you dont need joincolumn for OneToMany, then you use `setData` to $obj which is not clear what it does, because you do not show what is$obj, but seems the problem is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked objects can be "updated" if you setup `cascade=[persist]` in your relationship definitions. You also need @mappedBy and @inversedBy to be set for both sides of the relations. Basically @mappedBy is set to the oneToMany side (called inverse side) and @inversedBy to the manyToOne side (called owning side)

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

The proper way is basically

```
//assume $this->_doctrine is instance of EntityManager
$user = new User();
$user->setEmail('john@example.com');
$account = new Account();
$account->setName('john');
$account->setUser($user);
$user->addAccount($account); //if no cascade set
$this->_doctrine->persist($account); 
$this->_doctrine->persist($user); //if no cascade set
$this->_doctrine->flush();
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-associations.html#establishing-associations

Comment: `$em->remove($object_to_delete);`